# Check Date Format from a Python Tkinter entry widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Using a Tkinter input box, I ask a user for a date in the format YYYYMMDD.
I would like to check if the date has been entered in the correct format , otherwise raise an error box. The following function checks for an integer but just need some help on the next step i.e the date format.

```
    def retrieve_inputBoxes():
        startdate = self.e1.get()  # gets the startdate value from input box
        enddate = self.e2.get()    # gets the enddate value from input box
        if startdate.isdigit() and enddate.isdigit():
           pass
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Error Message', 'Integer Please!')
            return
```

Comment: I think @John wanted to know not how to implement a validate function but how to tell if the format is correct, in which case a regex would be the apparent solution. Google"regex date format YYYYMMDD". You might want to change format to YYYY-MM-DD as it looks way more used in real life.

Comment: @figbeam: you may be right. I've re-opened the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to employ regex. However, YYYYMMDD is apparently an uncommon format and the regex I found was complicated. Here's an example of a regex for matching the format YYYY-MM-DD:

```
import re

text = input('Input a date (YYYY-MM-DD): ')
pattern = r'(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])'
match = re.search(pattern, text)
if match:
    print(match.group())
else:
    print('Wrong format')
```

This regex will work for the twentieth and twentyfirst centuries and will not care how many days are in each month, just that the maximum is 31.

Comment: this is s great way to check the date format - i then removed the characters '-' from the date by using the replace command e.g startdate=text.replace('-','')

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've already solved this, but if anyone is facing the same issue you can also  convert the data retrieved from the entry widgets to `datetime` format using the `strptime` method, and using a `try` statement to catch exceptions, like:

```
from datetime import *

def retrieve_inputBoxes():
    try:
        startdate = datetime.strptime(self.e1.get(), '%Y-%m-%d')
        enddate = datetime.strptime(self.e2.get(), '%Y-%m-%d')
    except:
        print('Wrong datetime format, must be YYYY-MM-DD')
    else:
        print('startdate: {}, enddate: {}').format(startdate, enddate)
```

Note that the output string that will result will be something like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ssssss` which you can truncate as follows the get only the date:

```
startdate = str(startdate)[0:10] #This truncates the string to the first 10 digits
enddate = str(enddate)[0:10]
```

In my opinion, this method is better than the Regex method since this method also detects if the user tries to input an invalid value like 2019-04-**31**, or situations in which leap years are involved (i.e. 2019-02-29 = Invalid, 2020-02-29 = Valid).